# Get TRC20 balance of an address

Tags: evm, web3.py, tron

I'm trying to migrate some web3.py ETH/Polygon code to Tron.

```
    async def get_balance(self,address):
       contract_address = "0x2791Bca1f2de4661ED88A30C99A7a9449Aa84174"
       print(address)
       user_address = address
       infura_url = 'https://polygon-mainnet.infura.io/v3/<infura api key>'
       web3 = Web3(Web3.HTTPProvider(infura_url))
       contract = 
       web3.eth.contract(address=Web3.toChecksumAddress(contract_address.lower()), abi=abi)
       balance = contract.functions.balanceOf(Web3.toChecksumAddress(user_address.lower())).call()
       return Decimal(balance) / Decimal(10**6)
```

The above method obtains the USDC balance of a given wallet (on the Polygon network).

I'm trying to convert this to Tron and to get the equivalent TRC20/USDC or USDT balance of an addresss.

Problem 1:
There dont seem to be any Infura RPC nodes for Tron

Problem 2:
Whilst I've seen many references to using RESTful API's to get the balance of an address on Tron (mostly Tronscan API's) - I  wonder why I dont see any ways of getting the balance from the smart contract directly as done on ETH and Polygon (and I guess other EVM compliant chains).

What would be the best way to do this on the Tron network?